# Regular Expression for HTML attributes

Tags: html, regex

I need to write a regular expression to catch the following things in bold

**class="something_A211"**

**style="width:380px;margin-top: 20px;"**

I have no idea how to write it, can someone help me?

I need this because, in html file i have to replace (whit notepad++) with empty, so i want to have a clear < tr > or < td > or anything else.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this to capture the content:

```
((?:class|style)=".*?")
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE4wU8/1)**

However, if you just want to match and delete that you can get rid of capturing groups:

```
(?:class|style)=".*?"
```

Answer (score 1):

For all constructions like `something="data"`, you can use this.

`[^\s]*?\=\".*?\"`

https://regex101.com/r/oQ5dR0/1

The link shows you what everything does.

To explain it briefly, a non space character can come before the "=" any mumber of times, then comes the quotes and info inside of them.

The question mark in `.*?` (and character any number of times) is needed so only the minimum amount of characters will be used (instead of looking for the next possible quotes somewhere further along)